# Is blocking ads with hosts file slow?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 5.0-lollipop, root-access, hosts

For instance, Adaway offers a hosts file with 300K addresses to block.

It works, but will this significantly impact performance, therefor battery life? When does the system access the hosts file? Every time a connection is made, or is it just read once at system restart and stored in memory?

Comment: Normally, it is read once and remains in the memory. Do you have any statistics or any proof to even suspect that that file would impact performance or battery life at all?